# Database migration for .Netcore MVC project in Mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am just into dotnet and I am finding it difficult as most of the resource is available only for windows.

I have the docker running. When I try to update the database (dotnet ef database update) in the command terminal, it builds and shows an error saying "Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported."

The project is empty and its the default one after creating a new project with MVC

For incorporating Server in the visual studio I made few changes in the app settings.json

"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=leavemanagementnet6;User=SA;Password=MyPassword123#;"
},

Answer (score 1):

By default, it uses SQL Lite. Under `program.cs`, it should be changed to `UseSqlServer(connectionString)`.

Also, the default migration has to be removed and created again. If its not done, we will be facing error while updating.

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
dotnet ef migrations add CreateIdentity -o Data/Migrations
```